# StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo" on vb.net 2010 not working for jpg file but work on pdf?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, printing

I am trying to print jpg/image file in (theoretically) any type of file in background to specific printer.

so, I am using startinfo.verb = "PrintTo"

Here is the used code:

```
    Dim objStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    Dim objProcess As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim sreport As String = "d:\Wallpaper\Personal Picture\xVai\DSC_0000500.jpg" but not here :(
    'Dim sreport As String = "c:\Documents and Settings\y\Desktop\x\New\requirements.pdf" rem works for pdf file
    'Dim sreport As String = "g:\My Documents\Word\Budget.doc" rem even works for document file
    Dim sPrinter As String = "Microsoft Office Document Image Writer"
    Dim iloop As Integer
    Try
        objProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        objProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
        objProcess.StartInfo.FileName = sreport
        objProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = """" & sPrinter & """"
        objProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "PrintTo"
        objProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        objProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
        objProcess.Start()
        If objProcess.HasExited = False Then
            iloop = 0
            While Not objProcess.HasExited
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
                iloop = CShort(iloop + 1)
                cmdProcess.Text = iloop.ToString
                Me.Refresh()
                If iloop >= 300 Then
                    Exit While
                End If
            End While
        End If
        objProcess.CloseMainWindow()
        objProcess.Close()
        objProcess.Dispose()
        objProcess = Nothing
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

it works for doc, pdf files but when i try jpg file it not.

It shows error "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation" :(

I am so confused?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in your code but in your operation system configuration. Your Windows installation is not recognizing `PrintTo` verb for `*.jpg` filenames. As equivalent to action in code, you can test with generic Windows Explorer's Print action on JPEG's: if you get it working, then it should work also in your code. Try to register JPEG for PrintTo verb at operating system level.

More information: [Verbs and File Associations @ MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144175(v=vs.85).aspx)